# Cannot retrieve XML from InputStream using Java JSP when submitting from Adobe LC HTML5 form

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, livecycle-designer

I developed a simple HTML5 form using Adobe LiveCycle ES4 + SP1 which will submit to Java JSP. Also, I developed simple JSP to retrieve the submitted XML from request InputStream.

What I am getting on the server is the concatenated values of the form fields. See snapshots below for more details.

Download XDP file: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97clwYte2SHYTVaR3NEbEhkVUE/view?usp=sharing)
Download JSP file: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97clwYte2SHRWVzaFB1bDF0NGc/view?usp=sharing)

The following lines of code are used to submit the HTML5 to the JSP which are placed under the click event of the "Save" button:

```
var theBtnSubmit = cmdSubmitForm.resolveNode("#event").submit;
var theTarget = form_config.server_url.rawValue + "?" + "action=save" + "&form_id=" + form_config.form_id.rawValue + "&section_id=" + form_config.section_id.rawValue;
theBtnSubmit.target = theTarget;
cmdSubmitForm.execEvent("click");
```

The following lines of code are used to get the InputStream and convert to string:

```
ServletInputStream ris = request.getInputStream();  
String theString = IOUtils.toString(ris);
```

**The problem:**
On the server, I am unable to retrieve the form fields and values in XML format. What I am getting is the concatenated values of the fields which are filled in the form.

**Appreciate your help to solve this problem.**

[image: HTML5 Form in design mode]
[image: The hidden submit button cmdSubmitForm]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the above method is fine, the only thing is that I had to escape the XML output using the following lines of code:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils" %>
...
String theString = IOUtils.toString(ris, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
theString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(theString);
out.print("input stream in string format : " + theString + "<br/>");
```